# add hokuyu laser to quadrotor

Tags: hokuyo, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there a different way to do so,or is it similar to that mentioned here: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Adding%20a%20Hokuyo%20laser%20to%20your%20Turtlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247370/add-hokuyu-laser-to-quadrotor/) by [Siddharth](https://answers.ros.org/users/28449/siddharth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an example available within hector_quadrotor: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/indigo-devel/hector_quadrotor_description/urdf/quadrotor_hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro

This model is using [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) scriptping to re-use different URDF model parts and adds the Gazebo plugin so the LIDAR is also available in simulation. Specifically, it uses a macro from the [hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models/blob/indigo-devel/hector_sensors_description/urdf/hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro) file to add a Hokuyo LIDAR. This is different from the Turtlebot tutorial you linked, which only deals with updating the model without consideration of simulation.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siddharth](https://answers.ros.org/users/28449/siddharth/) on 2016-11-11**:
I am basically planning to add 4 such Hokuyo LIDAR(or even sonar sensors. Could you suggest me how to do that?